# JavaScript convert date to format

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to truncate a JavaScript Date object string from:

```
Wed Aug 01 2012 06:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
```

to

```
Wed Aug 01 2012
```

(I'm not particular, could be of format `MM/DD/YYYY` for example, as long as I get rid of the time/timezone)

Essentially I just want to get rid of the time and the timezone because I need to do a `===` comparison with another date (that doesn't include the time or timezone)

I've tried using this http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/date/index.html but it was to no avail. Does anyone know how I can format the existing string such as to get rid of the time? I would prefer to stay away from `substring` functions, but if that's the only option then I guess I'll have to settle.

**Edit:** I'm open to options that will compare two date objects/strings and return `true` if the date is the same and the time is different.

Comment: You could try out date.js as well, it's a library that lets you do stuff like just get the date out of a full Date() object http://www.datejs.com/.

Comment: @Martin-Brennan Thanks, but it failed when I tried entering the initial format into the 'Mad Skillz' box.

Comment: It should work if you get rid of the (Pacific Daylight Time) part of it, but I'm not sure if you need that for what you're using it for.

Comment: What format is your "other" date in? You would be best off getting them both to date objects rather than strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **only** way to get a specific format of date across different browsers is to create it yourself. The Date methods in ECMAScript are all implementation dependent.

If you have a date object, then:

```
// For format Wed Aug 01 2012
function formatDate(obj) {
  var days = ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat'];
  var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun',
               'Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];    
  return days[obj.getDay()] + ' ' + months[obj.getMonth()] + 
         ' ' + obj.getDate() + ' ' + obj.getFullYear();
}
```

Though a more widely used format is Wed 01 Aug 2012

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Date` object's [toDateString()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_todatestring.asp) method instead of its [toString()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_date.asp) method.

[**SIDE BY SIDE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Snowsickle/A6d8C/)

Even so, it might be better to compare the two date objects directly:
[Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-2-dates-with-javascript)

Comment: No, don't do that. It is completely implementation dependent and not consistent across browsers. W3Schools is a very poor reference, the [ECMAScript standard](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.5.5) is definitive.